# I want to perform right click using webdriver in Chrome ? Please Suggest

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to perform right click using web driver in Chrome ? Please Suggest

Below is the code I am using:-

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
Action action=actions.contextClick(element).build(); 
action.perform();
```

Comment: I am trying below code but getting error 
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);    
  Action action=actions. context Click (element).build();
              action.perform();

getting error as no such code

Comment: add your comment in question

Comment: That will perform a right click, what is your actual problem.  Do you want to select something from the context menu and you can't?  Do you want to take a screenshot of the context menu?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in c#

```
Actions actions = new Actions(Driver.Instance);
actions.ContextClick(element).Perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.contextClick(element).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

if you want to select the first option from the right click drop down.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. Please post the relevant part of the answer. If it's a duplicate, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
 Actions act = new Actions(driver); // where driver is WebDriver type

 act.moveToElement(webElement).perform();

 act.contextClick().perform();
```